# How can I fix permission issue when I cannot start Mac OS X?

Tags: startup, macos

I was creating a guest account and to prevent it from accessing the Macintosh HD as in other applications and stuff I assigned it as in "No Access"

When I switched to the guest account everything blocked, I restarted my mac and all I get is a blue screen.

Now, I can't log in, not even in safe mode.
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you running Lion or an earlier version of OSX? Don't panic, your problem is easy to fix, but we need more info.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you did?  It sounds like you may've changed the "everyone" permission on your HD to "None" in Finder's Get Info window, but it's hard to tell for sure from what you've said.

Answer (score 5):

Boot to single user mode by holding <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> right after powering the system on (before the chime & apple logo). Once the system has booted to the command line, type these commands without the leading tick mark. Spaces matter, periods matter, it has to be exact.

- /sbin/mount -uw /
- cd /private/var/db
- rm .AppleSetupDone
- halt

The mac should shut off. Now power on - you will get played the normal welcome screen. Make a new user (try not to re-use one of the old names - "rescue account" might be a good choice). You can then go to the preference pane and see what happened to the users.

Comment: The blue screen indicates the mac has finished booting and the user that is supposed to log in has some problems. Making a new user should solve it. If this doesn't work, you've got deeper problems and might need the boot DVD or assistance in reloading the OS since the OS should always work to make a new user this way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I tried the answer that bmike provided, logged in on a new account and repaired my disk permissions.
After that I could login again.

Comment: This should be a comment, not a answer.

Comment: Albeit the fact I extended the initial solution with another piece of help. Right...