# Login screen freezes after the Lion 10.7.1 update

Tags: macos, performance, upgrade, login

After updating to 10.7.1 (the first Lion update) & restarting the system, it's not logging me in. As I give my password and press return it stays on the same login screen. I could move the mouse but there is no rotating wheel, just the same login screen. I tried starting Mac in safe mode but same thing.

**Resolution**

It was because of Login Hook script which was stopping the login action. Booted in Single User mode and moved the script away from the expected location. Thanks to [bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike) for the tips.

Comment: Have you tried logging in to a different account?

Comment: Yes but still the same thing

Comment: This answer might let you make a new admin account and look and see why your old accounts are having problems. [How can I fix permission issue when I cannot start Mac OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20192/how-can-i-fix-permission-issue-when-i-cannot-start-mac-os-x)

Comment: Just the tip which was required. Actually the problem was not with User Accounts rather was with a Login Hook script. With single User control I moved that script from the expected location and I could log in. Thanks a lot for your help. Actually I up-voted your comment. You can post the same as an answer so that I could mark it as a resolution :-)

Comment: What is a Login Hook script?

Comment: info about hooks - http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html . This wiki is for git though, the same should apply here.

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/Ht2420

Answer (score 1):

If you have another mac at home, I recommend using the [OS X Recovery Disk Assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433) to clone the recovery partition. Then just insert the USB into the non-functional Mac and boot from the USB, as this will allow reinstallation of the OS.

Tip: only use these steps if the built-in recovery partition is not accessible. After taking these steps I would strongly recommend that you upgrade your OS (preferably to Mavericks) if you don't want this to happen again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather @kaychaks answer this since they took my hint and ran with it to find the culprit, but we have a question that isn't really answered - so here is the answer from the comments above...

You should be able to get further if you make a new admin user and log in to check if this is an account problem or a system problem.

[How can I fix permission issue when I cannot start Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20192/how-can-i-fix-permission-issue-when-i-cannot-start-mac-os-x)

Also, if you boot in single user mode you might be able to sniff around or just delete un-needed items to address the issue.