# User login password not working for sudo

Tags: macos, terminal, high-sierra, user-account, sudo

My user login password not working for executing sudo in terminal and I cannot unlock Users & Groups preferences. I tried to write password in editor and paste it but no success on macOS 10.13.3

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What's a path to get an admin account so I can fix things up?

Comment: Good effort listing users, but you'll need your admin password to enable root and the other two users won't be useful for getting control of the password again. I've linked to two resources to get you back in business in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trust chain can be broken in thousands of ways, so picking apart the specific failure might need some back and forth.

The good news - you can easily reset a password or make a new admin account so you can `su` to that account, then `sudo` or just enter the other user/password combination to unlock system preferences since any account can be used in addition to the logged in account to authenticate in macOS

Here's the reset one, two official article and article here on just making a new admin account by re-running the out of box setup process:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202860
- [Reset the password for a user when Snow Leopard is running as a VM?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41914/reset-the-password-for-a-user-when-snow-leopard-is-running-as-a-vm)

Also, use locale specific keys or emoji password with caution. You might retain one admin account and password with a long but boring standard locale typable password.

Comment: Thank you Mike for fast and helpful response. I created another admin user and change password successfully.

Comment: It seems that the cause of problem was different input source before and after login. Initially, the password was created by UK keyboard layout and later was added German (native layout). Login screen hasn't show input info by default which is very helpful to avoiding such issues.

Comment: @dado88 also, don’t put emoji in your only admin password. Lesson learned the hard way by me a few betas ago. Not sure if that’s resolved in all the places you might need to type your admin or FileVault password.