# macOS: Unable to unlock passwords under Safari Preferences → Passwords

Tags: macos, safari, password, keychain

I am unable to unlock the Passwords tab under Safari preferences in macOS Mojave .

I can see passwords in the keychain Access App, by typing in the desktop user's password. It works there, but it does not work when I fill the same thing in Safari, Preferences, Passwords; Passwords Are Locked. In the Keychain app it does not show the username it wants a password for, it just says, ....enter the "login" keychain password. Whereas in Safari, it says "To unlock passwords, enter the password for the user "Joanna". There's only her and Guest as shown users.

Oh, and Safari also quit saving usernames and passwords, even though it's set to do that.

None of my known passwords work, not my macOS user password either. How can I unlock this or reset it? I can't get to where website password saving setting are without unlocking this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97104/discussion-on-question-by-tim-sedory-macos-unable-to-unlock-passwords-under-saf).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User login password not working for sudo](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315087/user-login-password-not-working-for-sudo)

Comment: and also of [how-do-i-delete-or-fix-my-keychain-after-changing-my-password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153720/how-do-i-delete-or-fix-my-keychain-after-changing-my-password)