# Reset my Macs password? I still have SSH access

Tags: password, ssh, login

I recently changed my password and promptly forgot it :P What is the best option for resetting it? I can still access the mac via SSH (ssh key auth method), can I do anything with that?

Comment: Try this: http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/10/forgot-mac-password-how-to-reset-mac-password/ - Google is our friend :D

Comment: My preference is to boot to single user mode and make a new admin account. You'll need access to the mac locally either way unless you happen to have access to a second admin account. Then you can use sudo to overwrite the "lost" password.

Answer (score 1):

No - the typical ways to reset a password or delete the file that lets the Mac reboot to the setup assistant where it lets you [create a new admin user](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/41915/5472) that will have a known password all require you to know a working user/password combination that works for sudo.

You'll want to boot to the Recovery HD or install media or into [single user mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/20217/5472) to make a new admin user (which can be deleted once you've reset your password) or use the normal [OSX procedure to reset your password](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1274).

Answer (score -1):

If you are an administrative user (or can login as one on the shell prompt), you should be able to use `sudo passwd USER` to change the password.

Comment: No, that requires the old password. Unless you can run it as root, which he can't.

Comment: `sudo` should be enough, of course this still requires him to be logged in as an admin user (or to be able to ssh into an admin account).

Comment: thanks patrix, that did it on my ML 10.8 machine. i was working remote on a mac and the screen saver kicked in, and all i have is the password box. used to be able to put in admin username/pwd but not anymore, i think it changed in 10.7(?) I was able to ssh and use admin creds to sudo pwd change and then use ARD to unlock screen. thanks again!